# How to add ABIs for Android emulator?

Tags: android, vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to run Android emulator on Mac's virtual machine.

This is the result from `$ android list targets`:

```
Available Android targets:
----------
id: 1 or "android-19"
     Name: Android 4.4.2
     Type: Platform
     API level: 19
     Revision: 3
     Skins: WQVGA432, HVGA, QVGA, WXGA800, WQVGA400, WXGA800-7in, WVGA800 (default), WSVGA, WVGA854, WXGA720
 Tag/ABIs : no ABIs.
```

If I do this `$ android create avd --name myapp --target 1`, it will show error:

```
Valid ABIs: no ABIs.
Error: This platform has more than one ABI. Please specify one using --abi.
```

Since this is a VM, there is no interface (GUI).

**Question**: How do I install ABI in the `android` command line?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried this

`$ android update sdk -a -u -e -t sys-img-x86-android-19`

The got the error below:

> Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-5be876d5' [y/n]: y
>
> Installing Archives:   Preparing to install archives   Downloading
>   Intel x86 Atom System Image, Android API 19, revision 2   URL not
>   found: /home/vagrant/android-sdk-linux/temp/sysimg_x86-19_r02.zip
>   (Permission denied)   Done. Nothing was installed.

Answer (score 7):

Install the system images (x86) for the latest API (23) using

`$ android update sdk -a -u -t sys-img-x86-android-23`

To see a list of image ids use
`$ android list sdk -a -e`

where -a stands for all and -e for extended, -t for filter and -u for no-ui

Comment: Strange. Can you confirm if android-sdk-linux/temp directory exists and is owned by the vagrant user `ls -la ~/android-sdk-linux/temp`?

Comment: It said: total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root 4096 Sep  3 05:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 8 vagrant 5000 4096 Sep  3 05:20 ..

Comment: -e is not longer a valid flag, removed and it worked

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and was able to get past that part with the following(I'm now getting an SDL init failure: No available video device when running ionic emulate android).

From the command prompt after running vagrant ssh

1.`sudo su`
2.`cd /home/vagrant/android-sdk-linux/tools`
3.`android update sdk -a -u -t sys-img-x86-android-19`
4. Accept license terms and wait for it to download/install stuff
5. Close/Reopen command prompt and run `vagrant ssh`
6. You can now do `android list targets` and default/x86 should be there
7. Run `android create avd --name myapp --target 1 --abi default/x86`

Answer (score 2):

Try with sudo command.This worked for me!

```
sudo /home/vagrant/android-sdk-linux/tools/android update sdk -a -u -t sys-img - x86-android-19
```

Watch out the spaces in above command!